# How to set up Pit settings against Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku

I developed a Rails 3.2 application using Pit. It works in my local box. I want to deploy it on Heroku, but I don't know how to setup the configuration. Please let me know.

Here is my code using Pit:

```
pit = Pit.get(
  'my_app',
  :require => {
    'twitter.consumer_key' => '',
    'twitter.consumer_secret' => '',
    'twitter.oauth_token' => '',
    'twitter.oauth_token_secret' => '',
})
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = pit["twitter.consumer_key"]
  config.consumer_secret    = pit["twitter.consumer_secret"]
  config.oauth_token        = pit["twitter.oauth_token"]
  config.oauth_token_secret = pit["twitter.oauth_token_secret"]
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up using Pit against Heroku. So I am using environment variables.

```
pit = Pit.get(
  "my_app",
  :require => {
    "twitter.consumer_key"       => '', 
    "twitter.consumer_secret"    => '', 
    "twitter.oauth_token"        => '', 
    "twitter.oauth_token_secret" => '', 
})
pit["twitter.consumer_key"] ||= ENV["twitter.consumer_key"]
pit["twitter.consumer_secret"] ||= ENV["twitter.consumer_secret"]
pit["twitter.oauth_token"] ||= ENV["twitter.oauth_token"]
pit["twitter.oauth_token_secret"] ||= ENV["twitter.oauth_token_secret"]

Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = pit["twitter.consumer_key"]
  config.consumer_secret    = pit["twitter.consumer_secret"]
  config.oauth_token        = pit["twitter.oauth_token"]
  config.oauth_token_secret = pit["twitter.oauth_token_secret"]
end
```